# How do I run sample Caja(secure subset of JavaScript ) source code?

Tags: javascript, google-caja

Caja is the [secure version of JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/), developed by Google.  I am having trouble testing it out, i.e. in order to show a demo of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6) links to a [Caja playground](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CajaPlayground). Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is very helpful, I think it should suffice for our purposes; I was thinking of an offline way to do this though, I'll look into this more. thanks!